# How to share .env values loaded from API project to lib project in rust?

Tags: rust, dependency-injection, rust-cargo

I am  new to rust and am struggling with how to load up a `.env` file with settings/config values and then share this easily with Rust dependencies such as library projects. This is the project structure:

```
- apiProject
-- \src
-- \src\main.rs
-- .env
-- Cargo.toml

- libProject
-- \src
-- \src\lib.rs // <-- settings need sharing into here.
-- Cargo.toml
```

I have tried pushing the values into the environment and then ad hoc pulling the values in the library project but I get nothing. I used some `println()` commands to count the before and after environment variable count and noticed the value was not incrementing.

Comment: .env is used for local to directory what you ask don't make sense

Comment: HI @Stargateur - How do rust devs share a setting loaded in an api project and then pass through to library project ? Is this not a thing in rust ? How else can this be done? What is the accepted best practise?

Comment: My advice: Symlinks.

Comment: I will give that ago, my hope is that, there is a DI/IOC means of doing this like we can in c# with `IOptions<T>` and `.AddOptions()` middleware extension method.

Comment: Symlink is not necessarily a solution, depending on if you want your crates to have unidirectional dependencies. If you wanted to store the config in the API project and access from the lib project, then the lib project would have to know the path to the API project. And that would both create a dependency cycle and also make the lib not reusable anymore since it is tied to the API crate.

Comment: Use something like the [config crate](https://crates.io/crates/config) with environment variables as a source and pass around your config as needed

Comment: I would say that from a design perspective, and dependency injection of the configuration, a cleaner and more maintainable design (not to mention statically checked by the compiler for correctness etc.) would be to create your own `Config` struct in the lib crate, and have your binary crate (the user of the lib) then create an instance of the `Config` type with the necessary values and pass it in to the `lib` crate at runtime.

Comment: @ColinDBennett - this makes sense - such a struct exists in the api project, i can try moving this to the lib project then rebuild - i will feedback once i have given this ago. Thank you for the steer!

Comment: Also the config crate that @MeetTitan mentioned looks like a great option for the actual loading of config files (which you could then put into your own strongly-typed `struct` types to pass into the lib crate) if you want anything more complex or flexible than `.env` provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of loading environment variables from a `.env` file using the `dotenvy` crate in your API project's main() function.

Main function from `api_project/src/main.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    dotenvy::dotenv().unwrap();
    println!("API Project calling into the library.");
    lib_project::say_hello();
}
```

Then when `main()` calls a library function from the `lib_project` crate, the environment variables are available. Library function defined in `lib_project/src/lib.rs`:

```rust
pub fn say_hello() {
    let name = get_name();
    println!("Hello, {name} from the Library Project");
}

fn get_name() -> String {
    std::env::var("MY_NAME").unwrap_or("Anonymous".to_owned())
}
```

Example:

```
$ cat .env 
MY_NAME="Linus Torvalds"
```

Then, running the binary crate shows this variable value being printed from the library project:

```
$ cargo run -q
Loaded environment variables from .env file
API Project calling into the library.
Hello, Linus Torvalds from the Library Project
API Project done.
```

See [example GitHub repository](https://github.com/cdbennett/q-rust-dotenv-sharing).

Comment: Much appreciated Colin! That is exactly what i was looking for. I will give this ago and then get back to you in the morning.

Comment: It does indeed work as you provided, but the value passed/captured from the .env file feels like it can only be extracted and used once only ? like an ownership or scoping issue ? i.e i cannot call the `get_name()` and re-use the extracted values many times in the library project.

Comment: Not sure what error you're seeing, there should be no problem reading the value of an environment variable multiple times.  I updated that repository with a demo that adds another variable (parsed as a number) and uses the name multiple times.